# Elastic search substring match with positions unchanged

Tags: python, elasticsearch

i have been working with ES for more than a month. I am in search of knowing something relating to positional keeping substring match.

Suppose I have indexed a document to elastic search. 2 docs with "doc_field":document and with id1 and id2.

```
id1: " Once when a big Lion was asleep, a little Mouse began running up and down upon him. "
id2: " The mouse is very little"
```

I dont know whether I should keep the index "not_analyzed" or "analyzed".

What i am curious is if I am performing following set of queries will it be able to give me correct match.

```
query = { "query":
           "match":{"document":"little mouse","operator": and }}
```

I want it to return me only those documents which have "little mouse". It shouldn't return a document which has little or mouse at other parts. Simply, the arrangement of words in queries should be preserved. Help.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `shingles` TokenFilter ([documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-shingle-tokenfilter.html#analysis-shingle-tokenfilter)). It is very similar to the `ngram`, but using tokens instead of characters.

With default settings, it produces two-word long tokens. You can check its behavior with the _analyze API :

```
POST _analyze?tokenizer=whitespace&filters=shingle&text=The mouse is very little
```

that will output :

```
{
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "The",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 3,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 1
      },
      {
         "token": "The mouse",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 9,
         "type": "shingle",
         "position": 1
      },
      {
         "token": "mouse",
         "start_offset": 4,
         "end_offset": 9,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 2
      },
      {
         "token": "mouse is",
         "start_offset": 4,
         "end_offset": 12,
         "type": "shingle",
         "position": 2
      },
      {
         "token": "is",
         "start_offset": 10,
         "end_offset": 12,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 3
      },
      {
         "token": "is very",
         "start_offset": 10,
         "end_offset": 17,
         "type": "shingle",
         "position": 3
      },
      {
         "token": "very",
         "start_offset": 13,
         "end_offset": 17,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 4
      },
      {
         "token": "very little",
         "start_offset": 13,
         "end_offset": 24,
         "type": "shingle",
         "position": 4
      },
      {
         "token": "little",
         "start_offset": 18,
         "end_offset": 24,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 5
      }
   ]
}
```

Then, by querying on this field, you will see the difference between your two example documents.

You can find detailed explanation about proximity search in [this section](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/shingles.html#shingles) of the definitive guide.